# Cannot see reimported InfluxDB data by issuing SELECT query, where is it?

Tags: import, influxdb

Recently I had to wipe and reinstall my InfluxDB database which manages about 100 smart home devices from plugs to switches and a lot of sensors (/var/lib/influxdb was about 2GB). Since the sensors were continuing to collect data, I took the corrupt database offline, set up a new Influx instance which then continued collecting data. My idea was to inspect the broken DB and copy the intact parts of the data over to the new one later.

I actually managed to export most data using `influxdb_inspect export -database foo ...` to a file. I also managed to initiate a reimport using `influx -import -path ...`, which churned along happily for about two days, until my data was copied.

But when I issue requests now to the new database, the imported data is not found. It exists nowhere. Queries like before the crash only return data collected since the reinstall.

The filesystem size is similar so the data is in there *somewhere*:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo du -ks /var/lib/influxdb*
1910720 /var/lib/influxdb
1902236 /var/lib/influxdb2
1910284 /var/lib/influxdb-old
```

influxdb is the old DB, influxdb2 is the new current one, influxdb-old is a previous backup copy.

But a call like `SELECT value FROM my_measurement` which would return 100.000s of values from the old database now just returns a few hundred (collected since two days ago). Also all my frontend tools (like Grafana) which used to return two years worth of data for visualization now just show the last two days.

So: where is the reimported data gone?

I am using a Raspi 4b, Raspbian Linux, with ioBroker and InfluxDB 1.8.6.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

My old database had a different retention policy configured as the default, and the new database did not use the same default retention policy. And since none of my queries specified an explicit retention policy, only the data in the default retention policy bucket was found.

Re-imported all data with the retention policy set to the previous value, and everything seems to be OK.

It is possible to move data between policies, like this:

```
SELECT * INTO "db"."newrp"."newmeasurement" FROM "db"."oldrp"."oldmeasurement" GROUP BY *
```

but I ended up re-importing which also worked fine.

See https://community.influxdata.com/t/applying-retention-policies-to-existing-measurments/802 for the above command.